# Regular expression replacement of a text feed

Tags: .net, regex

I have a text feed file very similar to this:

```
F00020000100008252011
H123400010000050008201975
D23451234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D23461234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
H789100010000050008201975
D54321234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D54331234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
```

...where the line starting with F is a file header, the lines starting with H are batch headers, and the lines starting with D are detail records.  I would like to run a regex replace expression (.NET) where my result will be the file header, a specific batch header, and all the detail record under that specific batch header (and no others).  This seemed fairly straightforward, but it's proving more difficult than I expected, as is always the case when I start messing with regular expressions.  I am using a MultiLine Regex object in C#.  What can I provide for the regex string and replace string to produce the results below?

```
F00020000100008252011
H123400010000050008201975
D23451234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D23461234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
```

and

```
F00020000100008252011
H789100010000050008201975
D54321234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D54331234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
```

### Note:

While this application was developed in-house, and could be changed to support this in a far more elegant manner, that would require a code change, unit testing, QA, and change control processes which will seriously delay the availability of this feed.  If at all possible, I want to use the built-in Regex replace mechanism so additional resources do not need to be devoted to this task.

I have tried the following:

### Regex:

```
(?<fileheader>^F.*$)|(?<batchheader>^H1234.*$)|(^H1234.*$(?<detail>^D\d*$))
```

### Replace:

```
${fileheader}${batchheader}${detail}
```

and couldn't find all the details

### Regex:

```
(?<fileheader>^F.*$)|(?<batchheader>^H1234*.$)|(?<detail>^D.*$)
```

### Replace:

```
${fileheader}${batchheader}${detail}
```

and grabbed all the details, even the ones that weren't in the batch.

### Regex:

```
(?<fileheader>^F.*$)|(?<batchheader>^H1234*.$)|^H1234*.$^[D0-9]*$(?<detail>^D.*$)
```

### Replace:

```
${fileheader}${batchheader}${detail}
```

and only found the file header.

### Regex:

```
(?<FileHeader>F\d+\r\n)(?<UnWanted>(?!H1234)[HD]\d*[\r\n]*)*(?<BatchHeader>H1234\d*\r\n)(?<Detail>D\d*[\r\n]*)*(?<UnWanted2>(?!H1234)[HD]\d*[\r\n]*)*
```

### Replace:

```
${FileHeader}${BatchHeader}${Detail}
```

this gets me *almost* what I need, but only one of the detail records.

... and many variations along these lines.

Comment: Please post what you've already tried, too.

Comment: I should mention the lines are separated by carriage-return line feeds and the lines are all digits except for the first character.

Comment: so why do you want to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: This is definitely not a regex problem. (The only regexes you might need are `/^F/` and friends to read the first character of a line, but even that is overkill.)

Comment: Don't over-complicate. You can accomplish what you want by simply reading the first character of each line.

Comment: This is definitely not a good use case for regex...

Comment: I know this is not a good case for regex; this is part of a proprietary system that was not designed to do this, but of course it is now a requirement.  The system allows Regex manipulation of a file for simple massaging (commas to pipes, header rows, that sort of thing) so I need to get creative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer.

### regex string

```
(?<FileHeader>F\d+\r\n)(?:(?!H1234)[HD]\d*[\r\n]*)*(?<BatchHeader>H1234\d*[\r\n]*)(?<Detail>(D\d*[\r\n]*)*)(?:(?!H1234)[HD]\d*[\r\n]*)*
```

### replace string

```
${FileHeader}${BatchHeader}${Detail}
```

This will produce the following result set:

```
F00020000100008252011
H123400010000050008201975
D23451234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D23461234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
```

Likewise, replacing the instances of "1234" with "7891" will give me the other group I needed.  Thanks to everyone who offered answers, it set me on the right path to get my desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem may be better solved by using an approach like this.

Try reading each line of the file rather than using a MultiLineRegex. It's simple
enough not to require such measures, since each line should begin with only F, H, or D.

After reading a line that starts with F, the next line should start with H or F (use `StartsWith` in System.String).

- If the next line starts with H, we have the first batch header.
- If the next line starts with F, we have the next file header (no batch headers).

After reading a line that starts with H, the next line should start with either D, H, or F.

- If the next line starts with D, we have the first detail record.
- If the next line starts with H, we have the next batch header.
- If the next line starts with F, we have the next file header (no more batch headers).

After reading a line that starts with D, the next line should start with either D, H, or F.

- If the next line starts with D, we have the next detail record.
- If the next line starts with H, we have the next batch header (no more detail records).
- If the next line starts with F, we have the next file header (no more detail records).

This algorithm works similarly to a state machine.

Comment: This is not an option; I am not writing code for this specific transformation, I am trying to configure part of a pre-built process to produce results that were not envisioned in the original design.

Comment: +1 for not overcomplicating. Regex is not always the best solution!

Comment: @Jeremy: Maybe you should go into your *exact* requirements more, then? Peter O. gave the best answer for *what you put in the question*.

Comment: OP clearly states: What can I provide for the regex string and replace string to produce the results below? Don't know how much more exact I can make my requirements.

Comment: @Peter O: if I have to write a new transformer for this thing, I will do something along those lines; but changing the source code for this utility will throw me back into change control hell; unit tests, QA cycles, documentation, etc... vs a quick and dirty hack for this one type of file.  Your solution is cleaner; due to circumstances, it is not the most practical at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Regex wise. *edit* tested working regex

```
data = Regex.Replace(data, @"(?<F>^F\d+\s*)(?<FirstHD>^H\d+\s*(^D\d+\s*)*)(?<MoreHD>(^H\d+\s*(^D\d+\s*)*)*)", m => m.Groups["F"].Value + m.Groups["FirstHD"].Value + m.Groups["MoreHD"].Value.Replace("H", m.Groups["F"].Value + "H"), RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

No need to use Regex, something like this will do.

```
public String parse(String data) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String lastF = String.Empty;
    foreach(String line in data.Split('\r')) 
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;
        line = line.Trim();
        if(line.StartsWith("F")) 
        {
            lastF = line;
        }
        else if(line.StartsWith("H"))
        {
            sb.Append(lastF + Environment.NewLine + line + Environment.NewLine); 
        }
        else //implied if(line.StartsWith("D"))
        {
            sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The custom code route is something I'd like to avoid if at all possible, due to change control complications.  Regex replace support is a pre-existing mechanism possibility that I would like to exhaust before telling the boss the 2 day process will now take 6 weeks.

Comment: looks like this is going in the right direction, but I really need to boil this down to two strings that will be provided as parameters: Search and Replace, and I will be including the batch id (I've simplified it to 4 numbers following the batch header character in the example) to specify which batch I am trying to extract.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rough outline of what I'd do in perl

```
^(F[^\r\n]+)
.*
(\r\nH1234[^\r\n]+)
((?:\r\nD[^\r\n]+)*)
.*
$
```

In other words: F... to end of line followed by arbitrary stuff, followed by H123 at the beginnig of the line, followed by any number of D... records, followed by more arbitrary stuff.

(?: ... ) in the third item is non-binding grouping, allowing you to group REs w/o binding them to \N token. It is used to define RE for the D... record which is then repeated with a *.

This can be concatenated in the replace string with simply `\1\2\3`.

(I did not test the RE, but the approach should work).

Comment: This approaches what I'm looking for.  How would this look as a multiline regex?  The multiline parameter is hardcoded into the application (it was really meant to do something very different).

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know C# regexps well enough to answer. In perl, you mark an RE as "multiline" and "." matches \n like any othert character. Plus, rather than using ^ or $ you need to explicitly specify \n to match the end/start of line. Not sure how it all works in C#

Answer (score 1):

Could you use an expression like this:

```
(?<=(?<FileHeader>^F.+\n)((^H.+)\n((^D.+)\n)+)+)(?<BatchHeader>(^H.+)\n)
```

and a substition like this:

```
${FileHeader}${BatchHeader}
```

When I tested that with your example (I added another batch of details as a test to make sure it handles more than 2 batch headers per file header)

```
F00020000100008252011
H123400010000050008201975 
D23451234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500 
D23461234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500 
H789100010000050008201975
D54321234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D54331234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
H789100010000050008201975
D54321234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D54331234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
```

I got these results:

```
F00020000100008252011
H123400010000050008201975 
D23451234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500 
D23461234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500 
F00020000100008252011
H789100010000050008201975
D54321234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D54331234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
F00020000100008252011
H789100010000050008201975
D54321234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D54331234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
```

**ETA: I misunderstood what you wanted:**

I think this will work better:

With a substition like this:

```
${FileHeader}${batch}
```

and this RegEx:

```
((?<FileHeader>^F.+\n))(H.+\n(^D.+\n)+)*(?<batch>H789.+\n(^D.+\n)+)(H.+\n(^D.+\n)+)*
```

Gives this:

F00020000100008252011
H789100010000050008201975
D54321234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500
D54331234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500

Whereas this RegEx:

```
((?<FileHeader>^F.+\n))(H.+\n(^D.+\n)+)*(?<batch>H1234.+\n(^D.+\n)+)(H.+\n(^D.+\n)+)*
```

Gives this:

F00020000100008252011
H123400010000050008201975 
D23451234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500 
D23461234567891234567800000000000000000000000000000500

I'm just changing the suffix to the H there in the middle to match the particular batch.

Comment: Your answer collects all batches... I need the file header, a specific batch header, and the associated details for a specific batch.